# How to upgrade/maintain Libre Office

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice, versions

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
I want to know the following

- How to find the latest version of Libre Office
- How to upgrade to the latest version

Comment: what is the latest version for libreoffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first remove the old old one which has been installed

`sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

To Install the latest version:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

This worked for me

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties 
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice)

Comment: I definitely recommend the PPA way! Installing debs should be last resort.

Comment: but it didn't upgrade my libreoffice to 4.0 version

Comment: run this command to "sudo apt-get upgrade"

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 12.04, the LibreOffice 4 PPA which people mention above gave me some problems.

Specifically, it introduced an incompatible version of certain packages which broke the Apt system.

I wrote this script for use with the LibreOffice PPA instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Replaces LibreOffice 3 with LibreOffice 4.

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade

exit 0
```

In my experience, it works better with this PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Here is I installed latest version of libreoffice.

Download latest libreoffice from [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/).

Untar it archive manager , Find and  open DEBS  folder.

First remove older version with typing following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
```

Download latest libre office, and unpack it.

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xvzf LibreOffice_4.2.0_Linux*.tar.gz
```

Run dpkg in the DEBS directory

```
cd LibreOffice_4.2.0_Linux*/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *
```

You will get libreoffice with updated version. You will get notification when new version is available.

Comment: can you let me know the total process by command. I mean it by download link,untar commands. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- Open the Software Center
- Search for Libre office items & Remove them
- Follow the Original (normal!) installation Guide Here :
  http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/installation/linux/
  ( I'm Upgraded My Libre-office with this solution too )